# Save or Link to Files outside of Minitab Project

Tags: minitab

Minitab saves data in projects or in worksheets.  If the worksheets are in my project and I save, it does not appear the worksheets are saved also.  Instead, I have to save each worksheet manually.  Is there a way, either through the interface, or using programming to force Minitab to save or update each worksheet in the project?  Preferably, this would involve .CSV files only.

Comment: Don't understand the question. If you save a project (File > Save Project) the *.MPJ file contains all the worksheets in the project. If you save a worksheet (File > Save Current Worksheet [As]) you can choose the output format, including CSV. If you want non-Minitab files to automatically change when things change in Minitab you might want Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE), but that links to applications - not files. There is lots of help in Minitab on DDE

Comment: Thanks for the information!  I hadn't heard of Dynamic Data Exchange.  I will look and see if I can craft some sort of solution using this.  Also to clarify, I am looking to find some way to have the files that have been saved outside of a project update automatically when things change inside of Minitab.